# Problems moving Drupal to a new server

Tags: php, nginx, drupal, drupal-7

I have working Drupal project on an old server running Apache2. I am trying to move to new server running nginx+php-fpm. I also changed the site's domain during the move.

The move was mostly successful except a few details:

1. In the admin panel #overlay stoped working and every link (ex.: mysitename.org/#overlay=home/structure) rewriting to mysitename.org/home/structure. I guess I have some problems with new php.ini/nginx rewrite rules or something similar but cant find out what exactly.
2. After login user being redirected to mysitename.org/users/username but on previous domain user stays on page he was logging. Database and files of Drupal are exactly the same on both servers.
3. image_captcha module stops generating visible captches. Have read many topics about this module but no answer found. (GD JPEG support is ON)

Comment: Is overlay a requirement for you? I'm not blaming overlay, but I know plenty of Drupal devs that think turning off overlay is the first step after install. I generally avoid it from the get-go.

Comment: Verify your rewritesRules nginx , verify you have all of htacces from drupal , rebuild registry with drush rr , desactivate overlay module you don't need it

Comment: The problem was with nginx settings. Also php-fpm config was corrupted.
Thanks.